# RMAN backup is failing with write error on file

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, database-backups, rman

I am trying to take a level 0 incremental backup of my database on a linux server.

```
 backup incremental level 0 database;
```

When I run it I get

```
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on ORA_DISK_1 channel at 06/03/2020 10:52:40
ORA-19502: write error on file "/opt/oracle/product/12.2.0/rman/full_1jv1ql2l_51_1", block number 1195008 (block size=8192)
ORA-27072: File I/O error
Additional information: 4
Additional information: 1195008
Additional information: 995328
```

Checking the disk space returns

```
Filesystem                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                  7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                     7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     7.9G  2.2M  7.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                     7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                  30G   20G  9.2G  68% /
/dev/sda3                  19G  249M   18G   2% /home
/dev/sda4                 430G  255G  154G  63% /oracle
```

All the research I've done is saying that I'm running out of space but clearly I'm not. What else am I missing to get this up and running?

Output of

```
show parameter reco;
```

[image]

This is my RMAN configuration

```
using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
RMAN configuration parameters for database with db_unique_name ORCL are:
CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO RECOVERY WINDOW OF 2 DAYS;
CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION OFF; # default
CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP ON;
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '%F'; # default
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE CHANNEL DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT   '/opt/oracle/product/12.2.0/rman/full_%u_%s_%p';
CONFIGURE MAXSETSIZE TO UNLIMITED; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION FOR DATABASE OFF; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION ALGORITHM 'AES128'; # default
CONFIGURE COMPRESSION ALGORITHM 'BASIC' AS OF RELEASE 'DEFAULT' OPTIMIZE FOR LOAD TRUE ; # default
CONFIGURE RMAN OUTPUT TO KEEP FOR 2 DAYS;
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO BACKED UP 1 TIMES TO DISK;
CONFIGURE SNAPSHOT CONTROLFILE NAME TO '/opt/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbs/snapcf_orcl.f'; # default
```

Comment: Check /var/log/messages for anything suspicious

Comment: Hi @Mat I went to /var/log but there isn't a messages file.

Comment: Are you backing up to the Fast Recovery Area? What are the values of your DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST and DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST_SIZE parameters?

Comment: yes I'm backing to the FRA
DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST 

NAME: /oracle/recovery_area/PROD
size: 3.0065E+10

Comment: Do you have any error in the alert log when backup has failed ?

Comment: can you post a 'df -h' output?

Comment: @pifor where is the alert log? The only alert I'm getting is what I posted when I try to run the backup

Comment: @gsalem (Not sure how to add a picture)
/dev/sda4 430G 255G 154G 63% /oracle

Comment: The alert log directory is given by :`select value from v$diag_info where Name='Diag Trace'`;

Comment: @pifor 
 `WARNING: too many parse errors, count=1700 SQL has=0x750004bb
Addition information: ....
----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
  object      line  object
  handle    number  name
0x67cd8278       259  type body SYS.WRI$_ADV_SQLTUNE.SUB_DELETE_EXECUTION

0x6575ac88      2134  package body SYS.PRVT_ADVISOR.COMMON_DELETE_TASK
0x6575ac88      7342  package body SYS.PRVT_ADVISOR.DELETE_EXPIRED_TASKS
0x654ce1a8         1  anonymous block`

Comment: OK. This has nothing to do with backup. Could you post the output of `show parameter reco` run in SQL*Plus ?

Comment: Sorry but I cannot understand: if the FRA is defined with `db_recovery_file_dest`  parameter RMAN backup should be stored *by default* in the FRA and not in ORACLE_HOME. Do you have a special RMAN configuration ?

Comment: Please update your original to show the _formatted_ output of the rman command 'show all;'  Also your actual rman script.

Comment: @pifor I added my rman configs to the question

Comment: also your rman script . . .

Comment: @EdStevens I put the command I'm using at the beginning of the question.

Comment: OK.  RMAN setting `CONFIGURE CHANNEL DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT` explain why you backup to ORACLE_HOME. But as others have already said, the most likely cause of backup failure is lack of disk space under ORACLE_HOME. Maybe your database is too large ?

Comment: If I backup to the FRA instead would that make a difference?

Comment: It is possible because there is only  9GB free on `/` (and ORACLE_HOME is in `/` file system): it depends on the database backup size. You have 154 GB free on `/oracle` . I would try this, yes (but there is possible downside is that database backup will be stored on same file system as database files: you should copy a successfull backup to another storage system).

Comment: Ok I will try that and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to your output of "df -h" you are trying to take a backup under file system /opt which is located under / the free space is only 9G , the /Oracle having 154G and you need to allocate channel inside your backup script to determine the location to be /Oracle

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

regarding to my information "ORA-19502" is related to space or usually "The filesystem has insufficient disk space available" did you check that, or can you post the output of df -h so we can see it ?

Comment: I added the output for df -h

Comment: Regarding to your output of "df -h" you are trying to take a backup under file system /opt which is located under / the free space is only 9G , the /Oracle having 154G and you need to allocate channel inside your backup script to determine  the location to be /Oracle

Comment: This was exactly my problem. If you make it an answer I will accept it

Comment: And never forget **The golden rule of backup and recovery is: the set of disks or other media that contain the redundancy set should be separate from the disks that contain the datafiles, online redo logs, and control files. This strategy ensures that the failure of a disk that contains a datafile does not also cause the loss of the backups or redo logs needed to recover the datafile. Consequently, a minimal production-level database requires at least two disk drives: one to hold the files in the redundancy set and one to hold the database files.**